# Missing reference to Castle.ActiveRecord when compiling in Release

Tags: .net, castle-activerecord

In debug, everything builds normally.
When I try to compile in release mode, I get:

> "The type or namespace name 'Castle'
>   could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)"

I obviously have the reference, or the project would not compile in debug either. So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using trunk or some other version?

Comment: Perhaps doing Clean, before doing Build will help. Looks like Visual Studio got confused...

Comment: I'm working with Visual Studio 2010 beta 2, this might have something to do with it.

Comment: did restarting help? If not close VS remove .suo file and run VS again

Comment: Restarting and deleting suo file didn't help. I should never have installed VS2010 beta 2.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem recently (with some other assemblies). Restarting VS helped.

Answer (score 1):

I had to restart my computer in order to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS 2010 you have to change Target framework to .NET Framework 4, do not use .NET Framework 4 Client Profile